# Adding each answer from a loop containing formula to a list in C#

Tags: c#, list, loops, nullreferenceexception

I have a formula which calculates a number, then I need it to take multiples of each of these and store them to an ordered list, as many numbers as it takes to get to 300. I'm confident a for loop is not the best way to do this, but here is what I got.

```
public List<double> axialLengthFt(double length)
    {
       fundamental = (1130 / 2) / length;

       for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
       {    
           double d = fundamental * i;
           if (d <= 300)
              modes.Add(d); //NullReferenceException here??
           else
               break;              
       }
        return modes;
    }
```

I don't know why I am getting the NullReferenceException, please help!

Comment: Where do you declare modes? `List<double> modes = new List<double>();` should solve the problem.

Comment: As a field above, I forgot new List<double>(). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You are never declaring the variable modes.

```
List<double> modes = new List<double>();
```